# How to bound the uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ of the Bernstein polynomials of $ e^x $ to $e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, special-functions

I have a question:
How can we prove that the Bernstein polynomial $$p_{n}(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{n} e^{l\over n}\begin{pmatrix} n\\ l \end{pmatrix}x^l(1-x)^{n-l}$$ uniformly converges $e^x$ in the interval [0,1]?

My thoughts:
   given any $\alpha>0$,then we can find a $\beta$>0 such that |$e^x-e^y$|<$\alpha\over 2$, as long as |x-y|<$\beta$, then $$|p_{n}(x)-e^x|=\sum_{|{l\over n}-x|>=\beta} |e^{l\over n}-e^x|\begin{pmatrix} n\\ l \end{pmatrix}x^l(1-x)^{n-l}+\sum_{|{l\over n}-x|<\beta} |e^{l\over n}-e^x|\begin{pmatrix} n\\ l \end{pmatrix}x^l(1-x)^{n-l}$$,where the second sum is smaller than $\alpha \over 2$, but I don't know how to continue? can someone tell me how to prove this question without using stone weierstrass theorem directly. Also you don't need to use my methods, can someone tell me how to prove it ?

Comment: question is : how can I find a large n such that the inequality above is smaller than $\alpha$

Comment: can someone give me some hints?

Comment: The first sentence of the post is NOT your question.

Comment: what do you mean "first sentence"

Comment: First sentence: "I have a question: How can we prove that the Bernstein polynomial ... uniformly converges ex in the interval [0,1]?" Is this what you are asking? Because afterwards, you declare "question is : how can I find a large n such that the inequality above is smaller than α". Which is not the same question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we have known that $$p_{n}(x)=\sum_{l=0}^{n} e^{l\over n}\begin{pmatrix} n\\ l \end{pmatrix}x^l(1-x)^{n-l}=(e^{1\over n}x+1-x)^{n}$$.

If we don't need to use the  stone weierstrass theorem, then we can change our mind let us to prove whether $(e^{1\over n}x+1-x)^{n}$->$e^x$ uniformly.

So we can just need to prove that $n log( e^{1\over n}x+1-x)$ ->x uniformly, so we can just use taylor series to prove it, the  next proof just some simple computation.

If we use taylor series, we can easily prove  $n log( e^{1\over n}x+1-x)$ ->x uniformly. I think it is a simple method

Comment: write taylor series of $e^{1\over n}$, and then plug it in log function, and then change the log function into taylor series again ,and then we can find it is true

Comment: Can you explain how you did this please?